# Minimal or Maximal Von Neumann algebra contained in a given $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let  $A,B \subset B(H)$  be  two  concrete von Neumann  algebra.  Is  $A\cap B$  a  von Neumann algebra, too?

What about the intrinsic analogy of  this  question, as follows:

Let $C$  be a  $C^*$ algebra and $A,B \subset C$  be two  von Neumann algebras. Is their intersection, a  von Neumann  algebra, too?

Can one  speak of  a  kind  of  minimal von Neumann algebra contained in a  given $C^*$ algebra?

On the other extreme, can one  think of  a  kind of maximal  von Neumann algebra contained  in a given $C^*$  algebra?

In  particular what are two  maximal von neumann algebras in $B(H)$ which are not isomorphic?

Comment: For the first question the answer is yes, because intersection behaves nicely in both algebra and topology. For the rest, I prefer $C^*$-algebras over von-Neumann algebras, so wait for an expert to reply.

Answer (score 3):

The intersecion of von Neumann algebras is a von Neumann algebra.

It is possible for a C$^*$-algebra to contain no von Neumann algebra. For example $C_0(\mathbb R)$ has no nonzero projections, so it cannot contain any von Neumann algebra other than $\{0\}$.

If $A$ is unital, then $\mathbb C\subset A$, so there is always a von Neumann algebra. But again many C$^*$-algebras are projectionless, so $\mathbb C$ is the only one.

Even when C$^*$-algebras have many projections, it is very unlikely that they'll contain von Neumann algebras. It is common to find copies of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ (a von Neumann algebra). But any infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra is non-separable as a C$^*$-algebra, so no separable C$^*$-algebra contains an infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra.

And many separable C$^*$-algebras contain enough projections that one can find $M_n(\mathbb C)$ for all $n$, so there is certainly no maximal von Neumann subalgebra.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for your answer. by  Maximal  von  Neumann  algebra  i mean a  proper subalgebra which is  von  Neumann and is  contained in no proper von Neumann  subalgebra.

Comment: I see. I don't think that I can say anything meaningful, but I'll think about it.